# How to navigate from fragment to Activity in Android navigation component?

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack

In navigation graph, i have an Activity(MainActivity) which contains 4 fragments. I navigate that fragments using bottomnavigation view through ****NAV Graph**(JetPack Navigation)**. I need to play video using Exo Player.
So for that reason. i take a fragment which contains recyclerview of videolist.
when i pass the intent from VideoListAdapter Class like

```
             Intent intent=new Intent(context,PlayVideo.class);
             context.startActivity(intent);
```

for playing full screen video in PlayVideo Actvity

it shows me **error of **marshal value, & parcel.write.os()**** , so what have to do?...Please help me.

Comment: You could use another fragment and hide the bottomnavigation, or use a fullscreen fragment

Comment: It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](/q/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace.  If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using navigation component in your app I suggest that you should use fragments instead of Activity.

A quick fix for your problem would be to hide the bottom navigation view. You can access your bottom navigation using:

```
BottomNavigationView navBar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
```